# Are these images of carpenter ants?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

[image][image]

When I searched carpenter ant in Google, this looks kind of like some of the images. Some other images show reddish or winged ants and I have not seen any of those.

I've seen 3 or 4 of these big black ants in the last month we've been in our new house, wondering if I should be concerned.

Comment: Which country is this one from?

Comment: @Nakx - this is in the United States, Minnesota.

Comment: There are probably a few similar species that are hard to distinguish, but Camponotus pennsylvanicus is a common black Camponotus in the USA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Correct color? **Yes**
2. Proper antenna shape? **Yes**
3. Thorax shape? difficult to assess
4. Pinched waist? **Yes**
5. Heart-shaped head? **Yes**

Generally speaking, carpenter ants are black/brown in color, have bent antennas, a pinched waist, a round thorax, and a heart-shaped head.

And to address your confusion from seeing winged ants when searching on Google.. winged carpenter ants appear a few years after a nest/colony has been formed, so if you're not seeing any wings, it may be a relatively new colony.

One last thing.. carpenter ants (should) have hair on their abdomen. From your pictures I'm not seeing any hairs.

Conclusion: **I'm 90ish% confident that's a carpenter ant.**

Comment: i think the rings might actually be made of fine hairs... sucks to see these things in a home we just bought

Comment: That explanation is pretty close -- the more reflective rings on the abdomen are more or less hairless, the less reflective rings with enough fine hairs to scatter the light.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, the picture that you shared has ants with a striped abdomen, a characteristic feature of Carpenter ants.

[image]
<sub>(source: [doyourownpestcontrol.com](https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/images/carpenter1.jpg))</sub>

Wikipedia seems to confirm the same thing.

[Carpenter ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpenter_ant)

So I would say **yes**, this is a carpenter ant.

Comment: It is a Camponotus, but other genus also have striped abdomen (Formica for example).